# About invariant spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in M_{n}$ and $W\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$ be a subspace, such that $\textrm{dim}(W)\geq 1$.

If $W$ is $A$-invariant, then $A$ has an eigenvector in $W$.

I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Do you know Jordan Normal Form?

Comment: Presumably you are asking about an eigenvector in $W$ (the eigenvalue is a complex number, so not in $W$. Hint: Multiplication by $A$ gives a linear transformation $A_W$ frome the subspace $W$ to itself. Why does a linear transformation from a f.d. vector space over $\Bbb{C}$ have an eigenvector?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $A_W$ is the restriction $A$ on $W$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, then the polynomial $\det(A_W-\lambda E)$ has a root (= eigenvalue).